# Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=17 "The requested operations could not be completed because one or more parameters are invalid."

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, game-center, gamekit

In my iOS game I try to upload the saved game of my player into the iCloud to sync the process between all Apple devices like so:

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] saveGameData:[[mySerializedData dataUsingEncoding:kCFStringEncodingUTF16BE] withName:@"main" completionHandler:^(GKSavedGame * _Nullable savedGame __unused, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if(error == nil)
    {
        ret = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = false;
        NSLog(@"Failed to upload saved game data: %@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

However, it logs:

> Failed to upload saved game data: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=17 "The requested operations could not be completed because one or more parameters are invalid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operations could not be completed because one or more parameters are invalid.}

If I understand correctly, it will use the iCloud-Container to store the saved game, so I made sure this is set up, properly:

[image: Illustrating the iCloud settings of the project]

I can already log into the Game-Center on game start, I can also upload scores to my leaderboard as well as opening the leaderboard, so the user should be authorised.

How can I upload the saved game to the iCloud?

Comment: I know this post is very old, but there isn't much info out there on this issue. I am encountering this same error with my iCloud code. For me, it's specifically when I am notified of saved game conflicts, and try to resolve them. Did you happen to figure this error out? As far as I can tell, I am only passing valid data to the 'resolveConflicts' method.

Comment: @FunnerSoft Luckily I never threw away that old code. Check [this](https://bitbucket.org/MartyMaro/love2d-rich-ios/src/d47f4ef6d161ed189674b72125755aff1e062a1e/src/modules/mobsvc/MobSvc.mm#lines-237). This is part of a Lua plugin for a game engine, don't be confused about the poor await methods, it was required for the game module, but it worked, don't know how I fixed this error, though. The linked file should be relevant to you, as it contains the logic around GKLocalPlayer for downloading / uploading / deleting a single saved game. There is no conflict handling and the code it old, though.

Comment: Thank you, Martin Braun, for sharing that and responding. I really appreciate it. I noticed that your code does a gameDelete before its gameUpload. If the gameUpload fails, does that mean the player lost data? Maybe there is some sort of retry somewhere else in your code. But, have you had player data loss with the design pattern? Thank you again, I really appreciate the assistance with this. Cheers

Comment: @FunnerSoft Yep you are right, it's terrible and was never used in production, but it worked in my tests. I never completed it. However, the risk of failing is not that high, since the delete requires internet access as well. Also deleting the file would not delete your local save. You should maintain a local copy of the savedGame in your game storage. This way eventually the player can only lose his save game when overwriting from another device and downloading the new savedGame from the first device that failed saving. It would be better to implement resolveConflictingSavedGames, though.

Comment: I see. Thank you for that detailed info. I appreciate it. I am going to keep trying to figure out how to get resolveConflictingSavedGames working. It's amazing how little info there is available on this matter. Hopefully, I get it figured out soon. Thank you again

Comment: @FunnerSoft You're welcome. Once you have working code, it would be nice to share it, possibly as an answer to my question here, then I could mark it as answer and you could help others in the future.

Comment: I absolutely will. Hopefully, I can find the answer. I have been asking all over and searching everywhere. No luck yet =/